# Processing - How to make 2 moving images collide?

Tags: java, image, processing, collision

I want to have the panda (which the user moves with left and right arrow keys) collide with a candy image which is falling from the top left of the screen. When the 2 images collide, it would say "YOU TOUCHED THE CANDY" on the screen and the console. But when the panda and candy touch, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
PImage candy, panda;


int pandaX = 800;
 int pandaY = 790;
 int candySpeed = 20;
 int yDirCandy = 1;
 int yPosCandy = 10;
 int xPosCandy = 20;

 void setup() {
 candy = loadImage("goodCandy1.png");
 panda = loadImage("panda.png");
 }
 void loadStuff() {
   image(panda, pandaX, pandaY, 80, 112);
   text("Lives: " + lives, 1400, 70);
   image(candy, xPosCandy, yPosCandy, 187, 121);
   yPosCandy = yPosCandy + (candySpeed * yDirCandy);
   touchCandy(pandaX, pandaY, yPosCandy, xPosCandy);
 }
 void keyPressed() {
   if (key==CODED) {
     if (keyCode==LEFT) {
       pandaX = pandaX-20;
     }
     if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
       pandaX = pandaX+20;
     }
    if (pandaX<=10) {
      pandaX=10;
      lives = lives -1;
    }
    if (pandaX>=1500) {
      pandaX=1500;
    }
   }

 }

 void touchCandy(int xPosCandy, int yPosCandy, int pandaX, int pandaY) {
   if (pandaX==xPosCandy && pandaY==yPosCandy ) { 
     text("YOU TOUCHED THE CANDY!", width/2, height/2);
     print("YOU TOUCHED THE CANDY!");
   }

 }
```

I tried doing  `if (pandaX==xPosCandy && pandaY==yPosCandy)` But it didn't work. I also tried doing `if (pandaX>xPosCandy && pandaY<yPosCandy)` but it says YOU TOUCHED THE CANDY too soon.

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if you need more code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
if (pandaX==xPosCandy && pandaY==yPosCandy)
```

This will only be true if the panda and the candy are in exactly the same position. This is pretty unlikely.

Similarly, look at this line:

```
if (pandaX>xPosCandy && pandaY<yPosCandy)
```

This will only be true if the panda is to the right and above the candy, which is not what you want.

Instead, you need to check whether they're overlapping. You'd do this by checking each side, like this:

```
if(rectOneRight > rectTwoLeft && rectOneLeft < rectTwoRight && rectOneBottom > rectTwoTop && rectOneTop < rectTwoBottom){
   //collision
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on collision detection in Processing (including rectangle-rectangle collision) available [here](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

Comment: Thank you, I tried testing to see if they were overlapping like you suggested. I also made variables for the height and width to make it easier to understand. This is what I did                                                      
         if (candyX+candyW > pandaX &&
          candyX < pandaX+pandaW &&
          candyY+candyH > pandaY &&
          candyY < pandaY+pandaH) {
          text("YOU TOUCHED THE CANDY!", width/2, height/2);                                                I'm not sure if my math is wrong calculating the top and bottom, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I actually went back in my code and found that when I was calling the method touchCandy() it wasn't calling the parameters in the right order. It works now, thanks a lot for your help!